# How disruptive is an occasional exception to a toddler's sleep schedule?

Tags: toddler, sleep, daily-routine

My son's sleep patterns are pretty good.  We start our bedtime routine around 20:30 - 21:00, and he's usually in bed by 21:30 (and asleep within minutes).

We have been planning our activities and schedule around that routine as a fairly hard deadline, even on vacations and other special occasions, for fear of causing lasting disruptions in his sleep schedule.

He's almost 3.  What are the chances that a night of staying up late (for example, staying up an extra hour or two to enjoy holiday fireworks) would cause problems on subsequent nights (or mornings)?

What can we do to mitigate the disruption of such special occasions?

Answer (score 3):

There is no stronger influence on a toddler's behavior than regular sleep! In my experience, an occasional late night might mean crankiness the next day, which is usually rectified by the following day if the next night's sleep is good.

You might mitigate disruption by having a rest in the late afternoon, and making sure the day is fairly routine other than the special evening event. You might also make sure sugar intake is low. The goal should be eliminating those things you know might trigger a meltdown so that you are only dealing with a disrupted sleep schedule.

It's worth it for something as cool as fireworks!

Answer (score 3):

According to Marc Weissbluth, author of [Healthy Sleep Habits, Happy Child](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.amazon.com/dp/0449004023&sa=U&ei=ScDaUYe2Gerc0QHSt4HQBQ&ved=0CCsQFjAA&sig2=8eVpmLNsBDt2B9dS5Z99Kw&usg=AFQjCNHDHJEggrX55P9i8QUVwZMAo1dYyg) and other notable books on pediatric sleep, most children do well with about 80% consistency in schedule. Unfortunately the location where I found this quote repeated over and over again was his now-defunct blog "The Weissbluth Method," so I cannot point you to a source. His point was that life is not perfect and parents aren't perfect and kids can adapt. A return to the schedule the next day, or perhaps an even earlier bedtime to help make-up lost sleep, and recovery will happen. Unless you repeatedly give in to your toddler wanting to avoid the schedule you will not cause any lasting changes. I applaud your respect for your child's sleep needs, but an occasional change should not cause any harm.